# Jenkinsfile fail a step and continue the rest

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '7'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES')
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Admin') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        result = "FAIL"
                    } catch(error) {
                        result = "FAIL"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Normal') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                sh("echo 'hi'")
                    } catch(error) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fail the first step and have it show red and have the pipeline continue for more steps?

I have looked at all the SO answers for this and can't make it work.

Setting `result = "FAIL"` does not cause the step to fail.  How can I do this but continue the next step(s)?

Answer (score 3):

You can mark a build status as failed by setting a new value for the global jenkins variable `currentBuild`. The variable has 3 states: `SUCCESS` (green), `FAILURE` (red) and `UNSTABLE` (yellow). The `catch` should prevent the build from exiting so you can set the status of the `currentBuild` and simply continue.

```
           try {
               //so something
            } catch(error) {
                //mark build as failed
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
        }
```

I think this should work. Sadly I don't have a way to validate this atm. If it does not work, please tell me.

Comment: That marks the build as failed but does not tell me which step failed.

Comment: I thougt so. You can use an 'echo' command with some error message to display that an failure occured. On the other hand you can exit the pipeline always with 'exit 1' which will also show the "bold failure" on the GUI. So maybe put your other stage in the catch(){} and use exit 1 at the end of the catch()?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge we can implement same as below.

1. Use script step and try-catch block

   ```
   stage('someStage') {
   steps {
       script {
           try {
               //Do something
           } catch (err) {
               echo err
           }
       }
       echo currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can use propagate: false which is available in build step. Somethng like below

   ```
   stage("example") {
       b = build(job: "example-job", propagate: false).result
       if(b == 'FAILURE') {
           echo "First job failed"
           currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' // of FAILURE
       }
   }
   stage("test") {
       build("test-job")
   }
   ```

Links :
   https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

https://medium.com/@Lenkovits/jenkins-pipelines-and-their-dirty-secrets-1-9e535cd603f4

Comment: You'll notice that I'm not using build, and the 'sh' step does not have a `propogate` parameter, I'm afraid: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-sh-%20shell%20script

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show one stage "red" and all other (not failing) "green"?
As far as I know, that is not possible.

Do you want to know which stage is failing and which one runs correctly?
Well, it depends how you want it to be displayed

The easy way:
as suggested in a previous answer, you can use "echo" to print it in the console

The 'I want it full power' way:
capsulate a try-catch inside another try-catch and use the "error" signal:

```
stages {
    try {
        stage ('Normal') {
            try {
            /* Do your thing */
            } catch (err) {
                /* Mark this stage as "failure" using error
                error 'Stage Normal failing'
            }
        }  // stage 'Normal'
    } catch (err) {
        // here is the 'error' signal captured and omitted by now
    }
```

Stage failing appears with the text "failed" shown in the box and in a darker red